# How to make this Möbius Torus animation?

Tags: graphics3d, animation

I came across a beautiful animation of a [Möbius torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217513/is-there-a-m%C3%B6bius-torus), and I'm hoping someone can help me make this animation in code:

[image]

**What I've tried:**

I made the basic shape but can't get the right colors, lighting & reflections, and rotation to work yet:

```
makeShape[vl_List, c1_Integer, c2_Integer] := Block[
   {l = vl,  l1 = RotateLeft /@ vl, mesh},
    mesh = {l, l1, RotateLeft[l1], RotateLeft[l]};
    If[c1 == 1, mesh = Map[Drop[#, -1] &, mesh, {1}] ];
    If[c2 == 1, mesh = Map[Drop[#, -1] &, mesh, {2}] ];
    Polygon /@ Transpose[ Map[Flatten[#, 1] &, mesh] ] 
       ];
data = Table[{Cos[u], Sin[u], 0} + 
    0.5 Cos[v] { Cos[u/2] Cos[u], Cos[u/2] Sin[u], Sin[u/2]} + .5 Sin[
      v] { -Sin[u/2] Cos[u], -Sin[u/2] Sin[u], Cos[u/2]}, {u, 0., 
    2 Pi, 2 Pi/15}, {v, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/6}];
Graphics3D[{GoochShading[], makeShape[data, 1, 1]}, Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> {550, 400}, SphericalRegion -> True,
 Lighting -> "Accent", 
 Background -> RGBColor @@ {{0.1333, 0.1137, 0.5333, 1.}}]
```

[image]

**References:**

I've found these related resources:

- https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MorphingAMoebiusStripIntoATorus
- https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AFamilyOfSurfacesIncludingAMoebiusStrip

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I will add that, I’m stuck figuring out how to upload the animation right now:(

Comment: It's not a torus thingy, its technical name is *a Moebius thingy*.

Comment: For some reason the image upload from iOS app doesn’t work for gifs...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork ok updated

Comment: This is not a 3D object.  It is a sequence of 16 identical hexagons arranged in a circle.  The corresponding vertices of the neighbouring hexagons are joined to form a "face".  The hexagons are then rotated in unison about their individual centres to create the animation.  The tricky bit is working out the z-ordering of the faces to draw it correctly.  The colouring is also somewhat artistic.  It doesn't have any consistency for the specular flashes.

Comment: You can get rotation by putting the thing in a `Manipulate` and adding a phase to both `Sin[v]` as `Sin[v+p]` and `Cos[v]` as `Cos[v+p]`, and varying the `p` from 0 to 2pi

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Update: I have managed to fix the distortion of the polygons, so now only the glow is missing*

*Update 2: I have added a hacky "glow" to the polygons by adding partially transparent polygons slightly above the white polygons to give them some kind of "volumetric glow"*

*Update 3: I have tweaked the lighting settings a bit to give the image a bit more depth*

Here is my attempt (code below):

[image]

```
(* the color function to be used by the animation *)
colorfunc = Blend[{
  {0, RGBColor[2/17, 8/51, 26/51]}, 
  {0.9, RGBColor[7/51, 176/255, 188/255]},
  {1, RGBColor[1, 1, 1]}
 }, #] &;
BarLegend[{colorfunc, {0, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row"]

(* for each polygon, generate a random function moving between 0 and 1 over the interval from 0 to 2π *)
Clear@colors;
colors[i_, j_] := colors[i, j] = (
   SeedRandom[ToString[{i, j}]];(* make outcome predictable *)
   Interpolation[ReplacePart[#, {-1, 2} -> #[[1, 2]]] &@Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, Subdivide[0, 2 π, 8]}], PeriodicInterpolation -> True]
   )

(* precompute the rotation matrices for improved performance *)
rx = Evaluate@RotationMatrix[#, {1, 0, 0}] &
ry = Evaluate@RotationMatrix[#, {0, 1, 0}] &
rz = Evaluate@RotationMatrix[#, {0, 0, 1}] &
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[#1], -Sin[#1]}, {0, Sin[#1], Cos[#1]}} & *)
(* {{Cos[#1], 0, Sin[#1]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[#1], 0, Cos[#1]}} & *)
(* {{Cos[#1], -Sin[#1], 0}, {Sin[#1], Cos[#1], 0}, {0, 0, 1}} & *)

Manipulate[
 With[{pt = Mod[If[#2 == m + 1, l, 0] + # - 1, n] + Mod[If[# == n + 1, k, 0] + #2 - 1, m] n + 1 &},
  Graphics3D[
   Dynamic@GraphicsComplex[
     
     Catenate@Catenate@Table[(*generate the points*)
        rz[2 π (i + l j/m)/n].(
          {1, 0, 0} + rx[u].({1, 1, 1/Cos[u]} ry[2 π (j/m + (k/m (i + l j/m))/n) + t].{s r, 0, 0})
          ),
        {s, Subdivide[1, 1.2, 6]},(*add scaled versions of the polygon for the glow effect*)
        {j, m},
        {i, n}
        ],
     {
      EdgeForm@{Thick, Black},
      Table[With[{i = i, j = j},
        Catenate@Table[
          If[s == 0 || # > 0.9,
             {(*if the brigthness is >0.9, enable the volumetric glow by showing the scaled polygons*)
              If[s > 0,
               Splice@{EdgeForm@None, Opacity[5 (1 - s/8) (# - 0.9)]},
               {}
               ],
              Polygon[(*specify the polygons using the points above*)
               {pt[i, j], pt[i + 1, j], pt[i + 1, j + 1], pt[i, j + 1]} + s n m,
               BaseStyle -> {colorfunc[#], Glow@GrayLevel[#^10]}
               ]
              }, {}] &@colors[i, j][t],
          {s, 0, 6}
          ]
        ],
       {j, m}, {i, n}
       ]
      }
     ],
   ViewPoint -> ({0.3, 0, 1}; {0, 0, ∞}),
   ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 1},
   Boxed -> False,
   SphericalRegion -> True,
   Background -> Darker@RGBColor[2/51, 8/51, 26/51],
   PlotRange -> 2,
   Lighting -> {{"Point", White, {-1.6, 1.6, 1}}, {"Point", White, {-1.6, 1.6, 1}}, {"Ambient", GrayLevel@0.3}}
   ]
  ],
 {{n, 16}, 3, 20, 1},(*twist-offset along the big circle*)
 {{m, 6}, 3, 10, 1},(*twist-offset along the small circle*)
 {{k, 6}, -10, 10, 1},(*animation time*)
 {{l, 0}, -3, 3, 1},(*tilt of the small circles*)
 {{t, π/4}, 0, 2 π, AnimationRate -> 0.1, Appearance -> "Open"},(*z-rotation offset for the inner edge of the torus*)
 {{u, -π/4}, -π/4, π/4},(*z-rotation offset for the outer edge of the torus*)
 {{r, 0.4}, 0.1, 0.9},(*radius of the small circle*)
 ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

Comment: Wheres the shininess?

Comment: @user5601 As I have noted in the answer, I am not sure whether this can really be done in Mathematica

Comment: @user5601 Ok, I think I have managed to get some kind of glow effect, see the updated answer